# How to detect Socket/connection is closed abruptly in Python 3.6

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.6

How can I check if the client disconnects abruptly in Python 3.6. Here is my code,

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    print('Socket binding complete')
except socket.error as socketError:
    print('socket binding failed, ', socketError)

s.listen(1)
print('Socket listening for connection...')

conn, addr = s.accept()
conn.setblocking(0)
print('connected to ', addr[0])

try:
    while True:
        temp = conn.recv(1024)
        if not temp:
            break
        data = int.from_bytes(temp, byteorder='big', signed=True)
        print('value received,', temp)
        print('converted value = ', data)
except Exception as loopException:
    print("Exception occurred in loop, exiting...", loopException)
finally:
    conn.close()
    s.close()
```

This is working if the client disconnects normally, It is properly closing the connection. How can I check if the client disconnects abruptly?

Comment: This code seems to close connection properly in any way, since `conn.close()` is placed after `finally:`.

Comment: but if the client connection is closed abruptly like, the client is connected using wifi and he lost his wifi connection. then the script is not closing the connection, instead, it simply hangs up

Comment: You can create a thread from where you detect if connection is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can at the beginning try to send to the client a packet and with it you can see if you are connected to the client or not

```
while True:
    try:
        string = "Are you up?"
        s.send(string.encode())
    except:
        print("Can't seem to be connected with the client")
        # here you can process the expection
    # rest of the code
```

And in your case, you are already using non blocking socket `conn.setblocking(0)`, so even if the client end the session and you don't receive any data `temp`, variable will contains nothing, and you will break from the loop (That if the client is if the client send data at every loop)

Or you can also set a timeout for response from the client

```
s.settimeout(30) # wait for the response of the client 30 seconds max
```

and in the recv line you can do:

```
try:
    temp = conn.recv(1024)
except socket.timeout:
    print('Client is not sending anything')
```